# Symfony Doctrine APCu cache not clearing, "apcu_store" returning false

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, apcu

My PHP version is 7.4.3 and APCu extension is also configured and enabled. I'm using Doctrine APCu cache in my Symfony 4 application. Now whenever I try to clear the `result` or `query` or `metadata` cache I got following error.

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result

// Clearing all Result cache entries                                                                                                                                                            
[ERROR] No cache entries were deleted.
```

Issue is only for Symfony App. In core PHP `apcu_store` is working fine. `apcu_store` returning false on my localhost for Symfony app only.

Below is my doctrine config file

`doctrine.yaml`

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apcu
        query_cache_driver: apcu
        result_cache_driver: apcu   
        .....
```

Same code is working on my production but not on my local. Result not clearing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro in Symfony, but maybe if no cache entries were deleted, Symfony was not using it.
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/caching.html

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery('select u from \Entities\User u');
$query->useResultCache(true);
```

Are you sure you are saving the result before clearing it ? Never used apcu for results but it should work...

Maybe you could provide additional info about your configuration with a few examples.

Cheers.